# Control disappearing in designer

Tags: vb.net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

Consider an empty WinForms application created using VS2010.

It has a custom TextBox class with the following code:

```
Public Class DummyTextBox : Inherits TextBox
  Private Const FONT_SIZE As Single = 14.25!
  Private Const FONT_FAMILY As String = "Microsoft Sans Serif"

  Private Sub Me_ParentChanged(sender As Object,
                               e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.ParentChanged
    'this one does not work, it causes designer
    'to lose its controls once in a while
    Me.Font = New Font(Me.Parent.Font.FontFamily, FONT_SIZE)
    'if I use a constant value instead, like below, it works fine
    'Me.Font = New Font(FONT_FAMILY, FONT_SIZE) 
  End Sub
End Class
```

So basically a TextBox with increased font size, same family as the parent form.

What happens is that after being put on the form, and then built, the control sometimes disappears from designer view. If you run the project, it's usually showing fine. Close/reopen a form and it's there again.

Sometimes, however, the control will disappear completely (I was not able to reproduce this 100% of the time), so you'd have to add it again and set the properties. If multiple controls are placed in one shot, usually only one of them disappears like that. Controls are more likely to disappear after being moved around on the form.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research, `Me.Parent` can sometimes be `Nothing` inside `ParentChanged`, so that line throws an exception, which is never displayed to the user (it only happens at design time). Putting a `Try/Catch` around it helps verify this fact. It looks like *Windows Form Designer* likes detaching controls and attaching them back at its own discretion.

To solve the problem, need to verify there exists a parent, and only then set the `Font`.

So changing this:

```
Me.Font = New Font(Me.Parent.Font.FontFamily, FONT_SIZE)
```

To this:

```
Dim parent As Control = Me.Parent
If parent Is Nothing Then Return
Me.Font = New Font(parent.Font.FontFamily, FONT_SIZE)
```

Makes the issue go away and does not affect runtime in any way.